# Why isn't Ubuntu detecting all of my RAM?

Tags: upgrade, hardware, memory, ram

I just upgraded my netbook from 1 gb of RAM to 2, but when I type `free -g`, it only says that I have 1 gb. How do I get it to detect all of my RAM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `free -g` it show your memory round to non decimal numbers. Because of this it shows you just 1GB.

An example:
I have 8GB of ram:

1. `free` will show "8167800"
2. because it divides with 1024 `free -m` will show "7976"
3. `free -g` will show "7" because it divides with 1024*1024

So `free -g` is not really helpful if you have the typical among of memory for a PC.